# Estimate of an integral in one dimension

Tags: real-analysis, integration, estimation

Let $s,\sigma,t\in\mathbb{R}$, with $s<\sigma<t$. I want to prove the following estimate
$$\int_s^t (t-\sigma)^{N+1}(\sigma-s)^{N+1}d\sigma\leq \frac{\Gamma(N+2)^2}{\Gamma(2(N+2))}\vert t-s\vert^{2(N+2)-1},$$
where $N\in\mathbb{N}$, and $\Gamma$ is the Gamma Function. Any suggestion to obtain the constant $\frac{\Gamma(N+2)^2}{\Gamma(2(N+2))}$?

Comment: Do you know the Beta function?

Answer (score 1):

The following does not work (there is a reverse inequality), but maybe can be useful? (the answer is in the comments below)

Notice that 
$$
\frac{\Gamma(2N+4)}{\Gamma^2(N+2)}
= \frac{(2N+3)!}{(N+1)!^2}
= (2N+3) {2N+2 \choose N+1} 
\ge \sum_{k=0}^{2N+2} {2N+2 \choose k}
= 2^{2N+2}.
$$
Also, by the substitution $\sigma = (t-s) x + s$ one finds
$$
I=\int_s^t (t-\sigma)^{N+1}(\sigma -s)^{N+1} \, d\sigma = 
(t-s)^{2N+3}\int_0^1 (1-x)^{N+1} x^{N+1}\, dx.
$$
Now notice that $(1-x)x\le 1/4$ so that
$$
I\le (t-s)^{2N+3} \frac{1}{4^{N+1}} = \frac{(t-s)^{2N+3}}{2^{2N+2}}.
$$

Comment: Notice that $$\int_0^1 (1-x)^{\alpha-1} x^{\beta-1}\,dx = \mathrm{B}(\alpha,\beta) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}.$$

Comment: So, there actually is an equality if $t\ge s$. The request for an estimate was misleading.